# Git clone fails with "bad pack header", how to get remote log

Tags: git, version-control

I have a problem with my build system.

I have a remote server with a relatively large repository (around 12 GB, each branch having a size of 3 GB).

I have also 2 build servers (Mac, Windows) that are cloning the repo from the remote.

I am using [scm-manager](https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager/wiki/Home) to manage my repository.

Sometimes (very often when several git clone are sent at the same time), I have the following error:

```
remote: internal server error
fatal: protocol error: bad pack header
```

I know that it happens when the remote is compressing objects (thanks to `--progress -v` flags) because the last line of the log before the erro is:

```
remote: Compressing objects:  93% (17959/19284)   [K
```

- So I have 2 questions, does anybody know what is the problem and what should I do?
- Is there a way to get a more precise log from the remote to debug this problem?

I posted this message to git user mailing list and someone advise me to update my version of git. I tried with 1.8.0 on my remote server but seems to not solve the issue.

The bug has been reported to git mailing list (which is different than git user mailing list :))

Hopefully more news later.

After discussing that with the git guys, it seems that the issue comes from scm-manager.
I ended up by using ssh connection.

Answer (score 0):

Replace string in scm-server/bin/scm-server or scm-server/bin/scm-server.bat

```
EXTRA_JVM_ARGUMENTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dlogback.configurationFile=logging.xml"

EXTRA_JVM_ARGUMENTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dlogback.configurationFile=logging.xml -Xmx1024m -Xms1024m"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the log level of the SCM-Manager. Look for the file logback.xml, it is located at the WEB-INF/classes folder where your application server stores the scm webapp (e.g. /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/scm/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml when you use Tomcat 7 under ubuntu) or under conf/logging.xml folder in the standalone version.
Replace

```
<logger name="sonia.scm" level="INFO" />
```

with

```
<logger name="sonia.scm" level="TRACE" />
```

Restart, retry and check the logfiles.